# Table with both primary key and unique key

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key

My system requirement defines a unique business/domain/natural key (i.e. `<yyyymmdd><branch_id><running_number>`, in bigint). Should I use this unique key as primary key or I should still create an extra sequential primary key? My table is operation table and not warehouse table.

Someone with SQL Server experience advice me to have both sequential primary key and a unique business key due to performance hit with clustered index at growth of data. However, I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

1. Should I just make the unique business key as primary key, which simplify my backend application coding as I am using ORM (Hibernate)?
2. What benefit I can gain if I have both sequential primary key and a unique business key?

Comment: If you are really, really, absolutely sure that the PK value will never, ever under no circumstance change - then yes, use it as the primary key. If those values _might_ change, the this will be a bit complicated, because a PK isn't supposed to change. I don't see any benefit (at least not for Postgres) in having two different unique keys - especially not if both are integers (the situation would be slightly different if your business PK was a long `varchar`)

Comment: "unique business key" = ["natural key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key), " sequential key" = ["surrogate key"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)

Comment: Not sure what that person means about SQL Server, but in PostgreSQL there is no such thing.  Apart from this, +1 for @a_horse_with_no_name